# Последовательный вызов метода GMOCK с разными возвращаемыми значениями

Tags: c++, gtest, gmock

Для одного вызова ожидание описывается таким образом:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mockDatabase, fetch_row(_))
        .WillOnce(Return(row1));
```

Как можно описать ожидание двух вызовов метода `fetch_row`, чтобы в первом вызове возвращалось значение `row1`, а во втором вызове значение `row2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Найдено решение:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mockDatabase, fetch_row(_))
        .WillOnce(Return(row1))
        .WillOnce(Return(row2));
```